# Custom JPanel size always 0

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, size

I have been trying to understand what is happening here for a long time and I have not found the correct answer yet.

I am trying to create a JPanel from scratch; for this I have defined a group layout and then I have inserted the respective components accordingly.

the problem is that once the components are inserted, and also with their defined sizes, the JPanel keeps both sizes (width and height) with zero value. even after displaying it (without errors) on the screen.

```
public class PanelPelicula extends JPanel {

Pelicula pelicula;
JTextArea titulo;
JTextArea descripcion;
JLabel imagen;
int escalado = 40;
int escaladoX = escalado * 5;
int escaladoY = escalado * 7;

public PanelPelicula(Pelicula pelicula) {
    super();
    this.pelicula = pelicula;
    inicializar();
}

private void inicializar() {

    titulo = new JTextArea();
    descripcion = new JTextArea();
    imagen = new JLabel();

    titulo.setLineWrap(true);
    titulo.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    titulo.setOpaque(false);
    titulo.setEditable(false);
    titulo.setFont(new Font("Malgun Gothic", 1, 14));
    titulo.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    titulo.setText(pelicula.getTitulo());

    descripcion.setLineWrap(true);
    descripcion.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    descripcion.setOpaque(false);
    descripcion.setEditable(false);
    descripcion.setFont(new Font("Malgun Gothic", 0, 14));
    descripcion.setForeground(new Color(150, 150, 150));
    String generos = "(";
    for (String genero : pelicula.getGeneros()) {
        generos += genero + ", ";
    }
    generos = generos.substring(0, generos.length() - 2) + ")";
    descripcion.setText(generos);

    imagen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(escaladoX, escaladoY));
    imagen.setOpaque(true);
    imagen.setBackground(new Color(33, 33, 33));
    try {
        String poster = pelicula.getPoster();
        if (!poster.equals("")) {
            URL urlPoster = new URL(poster);
            ImageIcon icono = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(urlPoster).getScaledInstance(escaladoX, escaladoY, 2));
            imagen.setIcon(icono);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PanelPelicula.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PanelPelicula.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    this.setOpaque(false);
    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);

    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup()
                    .addComponent(imagen, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(titulo, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(descripcion, 0, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(imagen, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                    .addComponent(titulo, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                    .addComponent(descripcion, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(10, 10, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    System.out.println(getSize());
}
```

}

Comment: The panel won't have a size until the frame is visible and the layout manager has been invoked. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @camickr 
here specify that even once the panel is visible, it does not define its size.

The problem I want to solve is quite complex, but if I can understand this behavior, the solution is immediate.


these panels are dynamically added to a JScrollPane Viewport and then force it to go as far to the right as possible, in such a way that the last added panel is always visible. the problem is that since this size is not defined in the first instance, the ScrollBar always adjusts to the penultimate panel as can be seen in the following image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOaOW.jpg

Comment: @camickr the spected behavior: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKNAU.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> once the panel is visible, it does not define its size.

Swing components are visible by default, except for top level containers.

As I stated in my comment, a panel is given a size by the layout manager.

If you are dynamically adding panels to the panel in the viewport then the basic logic is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager

SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> 
{
    JScrollBar horizontal = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();
    horizontal.setValue( horizontal.getMaximum() );
});
```

The `invokeLater()` adds the code to the end of the `EDT` so it can execute AFTER the layout has been done and all size values have been calculated.